# pyparsing nestedExpr and double closing characters

Tags: python, pyparsing, column-types

I am trying to parse nested column type definitions such as

```
1  string
2  struct<col_1:string,col_2:int>
3  row(col_1 string,array(col_2 string),col_3 boolean)
4  array<struct<col_1:string,col_2:int>,col_3:boolean>
5  array<struct<col_1:string,col2:int>>
```

Using nestedExpr works as expected for cases 1-4, but throws a parse error on case 5. Adding a space between double closing brackets like "> >" seems work, and might be explained by this quote from the author.

> By default, nestedExpr will look for space-delimited words of printables
> https://sourceforge.net/p/pyparsing/bugs/107/

I'm mostly looking for alternatives to pre and post processing the input string

```
type_str = type_str.replace(">", "> ")
# parse string here
type_str = type_str.replace("> ", ">")
```

I've tried using the infix_notation but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it in this situation. I'm probably just using this the wrong way...

Code snippet

```
array_keyword = pp.Keyword('array')
row_keyword = pp.Keyword('row')
struct_keyword = pp.Keyword('struct')

nest_open = pp.Word('<([')
nest_close = pp.Word('>)]')

col_name = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + '_')
col_type = pp.Forward()
col_type_delimiter = pp.Word(':') | pp.White(' ')
column = col_name('name') + col_type_delimiter + col_type('type')
col_list = pp.delimitedList(pp.Group(column))

struct_type = pp.nestedExpr(
    opener=struct_keyword + nest_open, closer=nest_close, content=col_list | col_type, ignoreExpr=None
)


row_type = pp.locatedExpr(pp.nestedExpr(
    opener=row_keyword + nest_open, closer=nest_close, content=col_list | col_type, ignoreExpr=None
))

array_type = pp.nestedExpr(
    opener=array_keyword + nest_open, closer=nest_close, content=col_type, ignoreExpr=None
)

col_type <<= struct_type('children') | array_type('children') | row_type('children') | scalar_type('type')
```

Comment: This is an interesting project. Are you designing this format from scratch? If so, think about what these types are, and how they get represented. What is the difference between a row and a struct? And why does row use different grouping punctuation then array or struct? Why does the array in example 4 have 2 content types? Give these some thought, and then, before writing ANY code, write out a BNF of the format. This will be the roadmap for the parser code that you write.

Comment: Hi Paul! Really honored by your comment and solution. You're a legend.

Comment: This is for an open source data discovery portal called [https://github.com/amundsen-io/amundsen](Amundsen). We gather metadata from various sources such as hive and presto and make them searchable and discoverable. We don't have good support for columns with nested types so this is an attempt to improve that. I guess one problem is that different metadata stores can have different syntax for describing complex column types. This was my attempt to combine it, but perhaps it's better to split.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nestedExpr` and `infixNotation` are not really appropriate for this project. `nestedExpr` is generally a short-cut expression for stuff you don't really want to go into details parsing, you just want to detect and step over some chunk of text that happens to have some nesting in opening and closing punctuation. `infixNotation` is intended for parsing expressions with unary and binary operators, usually some kind of arithmetic. You *might* be able to treat the punctuation in your grammar as operators, but it is a stretch, and definitely doing things the hard way.

For your project, you will really need to define the different elements, and it will be a recursive grammar (since the array and struct types will themselves be defined in terms of other types, which could also be arrays or structs).

I took a stab at a BNF, for a subset of your grammar using scalar types `int`, `float`, `boolean`,  and `string`, and compound types `array` and `struct`, with just the '<' and '>' nesting punctuation. An array will take a single type argument, to define the type of the elements in the array. A struct will take one or more struct fields, where each field is an `identifier:type` pair.

```
scalar_type ::= 'int' | 'float' | 'string' | 'boolean'
array_type ::= 'array' '<' type_defn '>'
struct_type ::= 'struct' '<' struct_element (',' struct_element)... '>'
struct_element ::= identifier ':' type_defn
type_defn ::= scalar_type | array_type | struct_type
```

(If you later want to add a row definition also, think about what the row is supposed to look like, and how its elements would be defined, and then add it to this BNF.)

You look pretty comfortable with the basics of pyparsing, so I'll just start you off with some intro pieces, and then let you fill in the rest.

```
# define punctuation
LT, GT, COLON = map(pp.Suppress, "<>:")
ARRAY = pp.Keyword('array')
STRUCT = pp.Keyword('struct')

# create a Forward that will be used in other type expressions
type_defn = pp.Forward()

# here is the array type, you can fill in the other types following this model
# and the definitions in the BNF
array_type = pp.Group(ARRAY + LT + type_defn + GT)

...

# then finally define type_defn in terms of the other type expressions
type_defn <<= scalar_type | array_type | struct_type
```

Once you have that finished, try it out with some tests:

```
type_defn.runTests("""\
    string
    struct<col_1:string,col_2:int>
    array<struct<col_1:string,col2:int>>
    """, fullDump=False)
```

And you should get something like:

```
string
['string']

struct<col_1:string,col_2:int>
['struct', [['col_1', 'string'], ['col_2', 'int']]]

array<struct<col_1:string,col2:int>>
['array', ['struct', [['col_1', 'string'], ['col2', 'int']]]]>
```

Once you have that, you can play around with extending it to other types, such as your row type, maybe unions, or arrays that take multiple types (if that was your intention in your posted example). Always start by updating the BNF - then the changes you'll need to make in the code will generally follow.